# How to display the first and second Doctor to see a patient?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to create a table where there are lots of columns pulling date from one table and two views.  To display the columns is no problem.  The problem comes into play when I have to alias two columns to show a patient who received services from the first two distinct doctors (doctor_1 and doctor_2). Each doctor has their own ID.  I’m not sure if I should use the “distinct top (2)”, “rank”, etc…   Here is what it sort of looks like.

Date, LastName, FirstName, Address, City, State, Zip, Hostital, Room, Doctor_1,Doctor_2

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what? I don't understand what you are asking, are you saying that you have not enough columns to store all the data, if so, add more columns

Comment: No, i'm not saying that.  I'm not sure how to add the first and second times the doctor saw the patient.  The Doctor_1 and Doctor_2 columns are to be created with the two different doctor ID's that saw the patient.  How do I get the date for each doctor and have their ID's listed in order first(doctor_1) and second(doctor_2) and have all of them repeat for all of the other patients?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your table looks something as follows:

```
doctor_patients:

doctor_id int,
patient_id int,
visit_date datetime
```

In that case you can write a query similar to the following:

```
select a.patient_id, b.doctor_id as doctor_1, b.visit_time_max as doctor_1_visit_time, a.doctor_id as doctor_2, max(a.visit_time) as doctor_2_visit_time
from doctor_patients a 
inner join 
(select patient_id, doctor_id, max(visit_time) as visit_time_max
from doctor_patients 
where visit_time < a.visit_time
and patient_id = a.patient_id
and doctor_id = a.doctor_id) b
```

You can always put a where clause at the tail end and apply filters to the "a" table.  I am not sure if this query will run as-is because I did not try it out on SQL.  But I hope this gives you a general idea about what you need to do.  There might be better ways to accomplish this using latest SQL features but this should get you rolling.  I hope this is the answer you were looking for!